# Can I randomly select a Tkinter Checkbutton programmatically?

Tags: python, random, tkinter

*Disclaimer - Brand new to programming, with Python (3.x) being my choice of language to begin with.*

I recently completed a Python course on codeacademy in which I created a mini battleships game. As a learning project I'm developing a GUI using Tkinter and Checkbuttons for the game board so that it can be played outside of the interpreter.

I'm now blocked as I don't know how to have Python randomly select the Checkbutton position for the battleship location - and keep it invisible from the player.

Here's my Tkinter code so far...

```
from tkinter import *

class gui(object):
    def __init__(self):

        master = Tk()
        master.title("Battleships!")

        w = Label(master, text="Let's play Battleships!")
        w.pack()
        w = Label(master, text="Click in a box to try and bomb the 
Battleship:")
        w.pack()

        self.checkvar1 = IntVar()

        c = Checkbutton(master, variable=self.checkvar1, command=self.cb)
        c.pack()

        #Hopefully I can use this to display messages to user as they guess
        w = Label(master, text=" ")
        w.pack()

        Button(master, text="I give up!", command=master.quit).pack()

        master.mainloop()

    def cb(self):
        print("variable is", self.checkvar1.get())
        return self.checkvar1.get()

def main():
    g = gui()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Perhaps I should first create my Checkbutton Grid (5 x 5) instead of just trying it with a single Checkbutton (I was attempting to slice up my development into logical problems)?

Here is the original game code (no GUI)...

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

print("Let's play Battleship!")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

for turn in range(4):
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row (between 0 & 4):"))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Col (between 0 & 4):"))
    print("Turn", turn + 1)
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 
4):
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")
            if turn == 3:
                print("Game Over")
        elif (board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print("You guessed that one already.")
            if turn == 3:
                print("Game Over")
        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            if turn == 3:
                print("Game Over")
        print_board(board)
```

Any advice, hints, tips to aid my learning with this particular problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Advice: read more tutorial in using class until you're fully comfortable with it, the way you're using it, is very obsolete....

Comment: Hint: do the same thing as the non-GUI code, `board = []` and append the checkbuttons to `board`, just like what you did in the other code

Comment: Tip: don't do `from tkinter import *` but instead do `import tkinter as tk` , it will avoid possible namespace confusion in the future

Comment: Thanks for these @abccd

Answer (score 0):

You could always generate all your checkboxes (while storing them in a list when you create them) and then choose an item randomly in the list, store it, and when the user clicks, compare the one he clicked to the one you've stored.

Comment: Great suggestion. So generate it like it is in the original code (as a list). I'll look into that option. :)